# Why is Google pushing new Devs to Kotlin for Android App?

Tags: android, kotlin

Considering that starting from version 8 Java is much more clear and readable than Kotlin.

At the and Kotlin code get translated into Java anyway and it is very hard to understand what the code is really doing without plenty of comments that explains it, or autocompletition.

For example:

```
override fun onClick(v: View) {
   val amountTv: EditText = view!!.findViewById(R.id.editTextAmount)
   val amount = amountTv.text.toString().toInt()
   val action = SpecifyAmountFragmentDirections.confirmationAction(amount)
   v.findNavController().navigate(action)
}
```

How do I know what kind of object is the val "action"?

Comment: It's only more clear because it's the language you already know. It's a matter of opinion, but I think the vast majority of people who thoroughly know both languages would say that Kotlin is clearer to read.

Comment: Enable type hints in Android Studio, and the IDE will tell you what the inferred type is: https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/08/13/enabling-type-hints-android-studio.html

Comment: What i dont like is that we can`t control click on val to go to object definition, besides that i like val statements. but what I dislike in kotlin is the 'fun' keyword and return type after parameters, its just more words

Comment: Java has type inference as well, in java: `var action = SpecifyAmountFragmentDirections.confirmationAction(amount);`. What would you complaint now?

Comment: Why pushing new dev so much on kotlin if it has nothig more than java? Will they be able to get more money somewhere in their infrastructure?

Comment: `Kotlin code get translated into Java anyway` JVM Bytecode does not imply Java by any means, and anyway Android never runs JVM Bytecode, the compiler will generate dalvik executable which is what executed by android. The Kotlin is also going multiplatform rather than JVM implementation, the IR mode (intermediate representation) is released in alpha stage.

Comment: `Why pushing new dev so much on kotlin if it has nothig more than java?`, the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/comparison-to-java.html#what-kotlin-has-that-java-does-not) clearly mention what is available in kotlin but not in java, and what is available in java but not in kotlin.

Comment: The official reason they are pushing it is that they've found that it leads to more robust code. It's in Google's interests for Android apps by all developers to be more stable.

Comment: The other side of the issue is that Android cannot rapidly adopt new Java features. It's lagging Java releases by six years, but even if it were up-to-date, Java 16 still won't have inline functions or properties.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Is it more easy to adopt new kotlin features?

Comment: The Kotlin compiler handles compiling the latest Kotlin into Java 6 or 8 bytecode, so nothing has to be done on the Android end to make the latest version of Kotlin work. I suppose if they wrote their own Java compiler, they might be able to get the latest Java working on Android (without the newer stdlib classes and changes). I don't know if that runs afoul of intellectual property law. There's a huge lawsuit going on between Oracle and Google over Google's use of Java in Android.

Comment: google being a pr¡ck never tried to arrange licencing agreement with Sun. Sun accepted or rather overlooked this undetermined status. Since Sun is dead (rip) and oracle, wolfing down all its legacy, is not so easy for google to fleece them as they've done with Sun, google was looking around for someone else to provide them with a super cheap jvm based hlpg - and they found the Jetbrain guys who were selling this awfull IDE and now have built some east european/russian knock-off of Java (Kotlin is the name of a russian island) - also being equally awful as their IDE, but promoted as 'cool'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Considering that starting from version 8 Java is much more clear and readable than Kotlin

Its just matter of taste, everybody has his own opinion, similar to your consideration Google team may found Kotlin good option to be more clear and concise.

> Why pushing new dev so much on kotlin if it has nothig more than java?

Kotlin is alot different than just plain Java, the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/comparison-to-java.html#what-kotlin-has-that-java-does-not) itself say much about it, here's brief differences:

- **Null-safety** - Kotlin's type system is aimed at eliminating the danger of null references from code, also known as the [The Billion Dollar Mistake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare#Apologies_and_retractions).

  Your app won't even compile until you remove all possibilities of NPE, otherwise you decide to axing your own feet by null-assertion operator (`!!`)
- **Coroutines** - Light weight implementation of concurrency model, not only limited to multi-threading but also to the extent of doing [deep-recursion](https://medium.com/@elizarov/deep-recursion-with-coroutines-7c53e15993e3), [shared mutable-state and structured-concurrency](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/shared-mutable-state-and-concurrency.html), and also provides a lot of standard utilities for faster development like [Flows](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/flow.html). Being a lightweight implementation it is slightly faster in many situations than its competitors like RxJava.
- **Immutability** - Proper handling of Collections (difference in read-only and mutable).

  Similar goes to variables, Kotlin by default instructs you to use val until you required to change it later in order to provide a thread-safety.
- **Declaration-site Variance** - Kotlin allows you to specify [generic variances at declaration-site](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html) that will save you a lot of time, and hence less bugs.
- **Proper function types (i.e. lambda) and higher order functions** - There's native support for the [lambda expressions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html), and the support for the [inline function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html) makes it possible to counter the performance overhead of memory allocations (both for function objects and classes) and virtual calls introduce runtime overhead.
- **Smart-casts** - no need to cast an object when checks have been made.

  ```kotlin
  if (variable is String) {
      println(variable.length)  // no need to cast to String :P
  }
  ```
- Functional extensions - [let](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html), [run](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run.html), [also](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/also.html), [apply](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html), [with](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/with.html), [use](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/use.html). These are very useful in concise code and hence boosts productivity.

  ```java
  // Java version
  var a = Api.result();
  Log.i(Tag, a.toString());
  return a;

  // Kotlin version
  return Api.result().also { Log.i(Tag, it.toString()) }
  ```
- **Default parameters** - You can mark a field as optional and just use 1 single function which is easier to manage later on rather than overloading function like 5 times and manage them all when updating a piece of code.
- **Native support for delegation** - Defining getters and setters once and use them for as many field/properties as you want. There are [delegates provided by std-lib](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#standard-delegates) like lazy (do-not allocate memory in RAM till property is accessed for the first time), observable (observe the changes in variable with both old and new value), etc.
- **Delegation of classes** - You can implement a class using another object, useful when you want to extend some functionality of class but want to let other untouched. For examples see: [Delegation of Classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html)
- **Inline functions and reified generics** - In java it is impossible to use generics inside of a function because of JVM type-erasure. But this is not the case in Kotlin, you can embed the function into the callsite (at the compile time) using [inline modifier](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html) and access generics via making it [reified](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters).
- **Destructing Declarations** - Create multiple variable in same line using a destructing object, see [Kotlin: Destructuring Declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html) for examples.

#### Edit:

Forgot to put the answer to the code block, the `amount` has the same type returned by `toInt()`, and `action` has the same type as returned by `confirmationAction(amount)`. Using an IDE will show that to you the inferred types in front of the variable names, you can also jump at the sources through some `Ctrl+MouseClick` at the call-site.

Comment: Ok, the question was closed when I selected the answer, I think you were writing meanwhile. I appreciate the effort. I never change value allocation for respect, but since it is just few points on a -4 question i will make an "exception" thanks

Comment: The accepted answer should always be changed to the most useful one. A big goal of this site is to help people find answers to their questions without having to write new ones.

Comment: @Tenfour04 yes I understand, this will help SOW to minimize data and have a cleaner db so to reduce expenses. But in general there is no perfect question nor answer.I've learnt many things from secondary asnwer or wrong questions

Answer (score -1):

type of val `action` is same as the return type of `confirmationAction` method in `SpecifyAmountFragmentDirections` class

It's just that you have been using Java for long time and new to kotlin so you finding kotlin hard to understand.It's just matter of time and once you start using it regularly you will find it easier to understand and read.Moreover lines of code usually becomes less in kotlin.

**UPDATE based on comments-**

Kotlin has some advantages in comparison to java like it is more safe against NullPointerException which all android developers face many times in java and it is less verbose and less code can mean chances of fewer bugs.So new developers are recommended to learn kotlin for android.

Comment: Ok but that static method could have an arbitrary name

Comment: @zmho i don't understand  what you mean..whatever will be return type of confirmationAction method that will be the type of action field ..that answers what what kind of object is val "action" is which OP wants to know!

Comment: Downvoted because you're just guessing why OP finds kotlin harder to read, and assuming when (and that) it will become easier for them than java is

Comment: maybe the question is not really clear. Google is using money to write new documentation for kotlin and promote it so devs think is better than java...why are the fighting this economic friction at thei expenses? will they be able to.make more money woth kotlin?

Comment: *it is safe against NullPointerException* not true. *less code means fewer bugs* not true. I would downvote again if I could.

Comment: @Tim updated.. it is more safe against NullPointerException and less code can mean chances of fewer bugs..If for same thing same developer is writing 50 lines of code in one language and 100 lines of code in another language than we say that 50 lines of code has chances of fewer bugs although it is not necessary..

Comment: @Tim if your program has NullException means that the code has a logic flaw, it helps to understand that your code should be changed. And the thing about less code is completely wrong, just marketing for devs to prefer kotlin over java

Comment: @zmho in kotlin if a field is nullable,the compiler will force you to check the null before doing anything with the variable. This ensures that a NullPointerException doesn’t occur.This compile time verification was not there in java which make developers easier to avoid nullpointerexception in kotlin..I am not from kotlin team that i am marketing for devs to prefer kotlin.I have used java and kotlin both and just answering your question that why new devlopers are recommended to learn kotlin for android.It is better you have good knowledge for both java and kotlin if you are android developer

Comment: @Android Developer ok, but now it has the verification, Java is robust enough, they use it until now. Why did they change idea?

Comment: @zmho `but now it has the verification,` i think java still doesn't have compile time verfication for nullable fields..Secondly if you have project running in java there is no need to change already created things to kotlin.Kotlin is designed with Java Interoperability in mind. Existing Java code can be called from Kotlin in a natural way,It's just for the new code that you need to decide whether you need to use kotlin or java.If you have good knowledge in both than using kotlin can be good choice as it has some features that java doesn't have

Comment: In my humble opinion, these are all pretty lame reasons.  Are you relying on a compiler to write "good code"?  Every developer has a good reason for choosing a specific language over another.  Although no one wants to admit it, Google is forcing developers to use Kotlin by removing Java Samples.  Dare I say that it is because Google has an axe to grind with Oracle?  Yes, I dare.  If you prefer Kotlin, use it but don't make excuses for Google.

Comment: @mikeB now with Jetpack Compose introduced in kotlin and with Coroutines already there in kotlin,I can surely say that kotlin is great to work with in android!!I not making excuses for anyone..I just giving my opinion!!